# Trying to get the value of an element inside the xml of an Xelement

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

I have an Xelement being passed into a function:

```
ByVal request As XElement
```

inside the Xelement object is an element:

```
<nc:ID>1234567</nc:ID>
```

I should be able to get this value by:

```
request.Element("ID").value
```

...but it does not return anything. I suspect this is because of the namespace prefix. I saw a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691750/using-the-xelement-elements-method-can-i-find-elements-with-wildcard-namespace) which after translating to VB.net (`request.Elements().Where(Function(e) e.Name.LocalName = "ID").Value`) works, but I do not understand why or why the .element("ID").value does not return the value. Can anyone give me some insight into this?

Comment: Have you tried using XmlReader, and XmlWriter? Or is that not an option?

Comment: @ChaseErnst My web service is consuming and returning Xelements so I was trying to use the methods associated with this object type. CreateReader will instantiate an xmlreader for the Xelement, but I think that is overkill since this object has simplified some of the tasks like getting an element value.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today.  Apparently "nc" is not the namespace, but is in fact the namespace prefix; you need to get the namespace itself.  Here's how it turns out it has to be done:

```
XNamespace ns = request.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("nc");
XElement ID = request.Element(ns + "ID");
```